# C++ not a type error when declaring a vector in a struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct, stl, stdvector

I wish to have a node data structure which contains a vector. I know the size of the vector before hand, hence I initialize a `SIZE` variable upfront with a `const` specifier.

#### CODE (`vectorTest.cpp`):

```
#include <vector>

const int SIZE = 100;

struct node {
  std::vector<int> myVec(SIZE); // ERROR: 'SIZE' is not a type
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  std::vector<int> myVec(SIZE); // VALID
  return 0;
}
```

#### COMPILE (`g++ 5.4.0`):

```
g++ -std=c++1y vectorTest.cpp -o vectorTest
```

Inside `main()`, everything is fine and I can happily declare:       `std::vector<int> A(SIZE);`. However, when I try to define the same inside a `struct`, I get an error saying that `'SIZE' is not a type`.

I am aware that I can do this to declare a vector of `int`s using C-style array definition,

```
struct other_node {
  int myVec[SIZE]; // VALID
};
```

But I am wondering why this isn't possible with `std::vector`.

#### QUESTIONS:

- What does this error mean?
- Why can I not declare a vector of predefined size inside a `struct`?

Comment: If you know the size at compile time, why not use `std::array`?

Comment: I can't find the duplicate now, but it's because of the syntax you use for the `node::myVec` is used to declare a function. For inline initialization you must use `=` or brace-initialization (`{}`), or constructor initializer lists of course. Otherwise, how would the compiler differ between a member function and a member variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does this error mean?

The compiler is expecting a function declaration in the line. Hence, it is expecting a type instead of a value.

> Why can I not declare a vector of predefined size inside a `struct`?

You can use:

```
// Legal but it initializes myVector with one element whose value is SIZE.
// std::vector<int> myVec{SIZE};
std::vector<int> myVec = std::vector<int>(SIZE);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, since I'm not too familiar with C++11 and beyond, why doesn't that init the vector with a single element with value `SIZE`?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, use of  `T t(val);` is not valid for in-member initialization. `T t{val};` and `T t = val;` are valid forms.

Comment: It's not Remy who has that backwards but this answer. If I understand http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5c8ecf0e4fb65ef right, the single parameter turns into a single element here, not a vector with the given size!

Answer (score 4):

The compiler doesn't expect an initialization at that point inside a type definition (it doesn't matter that it's a `struct`, could be a `class` or `union`, too). The only thing valid would be a declaration of a member function, which has the structure `<returntype> <name>(<arguments...>)`. For the arguments, you can leave out the name and just provide the type. In this case, it's `SIZE`, but since that's not a type, you get the error.

Working alternatives:

- Declaring a constructor and initializing the vector there.
- Initalizing with a vector of the wanted size: `vector<int> myVec = vector<int>(SIZE);`

Notes:

- A similar error is known as the "most vexing parse of C++".
- Using `ALL_UPPERCASE` should always and only used for macros. This convention helps you spot them, it's like a warning for their different behaviour.

Comment: In C++11 and later, class/struct member declarations can have initializations.

Comment: True. The valid one uses an initializer list, but how'd you call that particular syntax that's not valid in this context?

Comment: `struct node { std::vector<int> myVec = std::vector<int>(SIZE); };` Otherwise, you can declare a constructor with a member initialization list (which will also work in pre-C++11 compilers): `struct node { std::vector<int> myVec; node() : myVec(SIZE) {} };`

Comment: @liliscent: fixed

Comment: Sorry @RemyLebeau, misunderstanding: I was wondering what the name was, not how to invoke it. :)